# Cluster analysis - multiparametric

Tags: math, analysis

I have a following problem Im trying to solve.
I have hundreds of particles with their corresponding chemical composition (elements with their weight percentages).

As an example, here are some made-up simplified particles:

Particle 1 - S (32%), K (25%), C (43%)

Particle 2 - S (33%), K (12%), C (15%), O (40%)

Particle 3 - Ti (18%), S (72%)

Particle 4 - Ti (10%), S (79%), K (12%)

In reality there are hundreds of them, some of them quite different to one another, some of them quite similar. As you can see, some particles do not have certain elements (i.e. they could be used as 0%).

What I would try to achieve is perform a cluster analysis, that would group the particles into groups with similar particles and give me some averages in terms of that cluster element composition.

I was looking at how cluster analysis works, but usually it only uses 2 parameters, whereas I have many elements for each particle and I want to take into account more than just one element for each particle while clustering it. I am not so much interested in the exact match in terms of all the elements contained. In other words, if for example some 2 particles were quite similar except that one contained one extra element in a very small quantity, that would be ok too. Very low percentages are sometimes caused by background noise when measuring it.

Once I know which strategy to use I would ideally use R to do it. But giving me just a hint as to how to go about it, or a link, would be enough.

Comment: Since this is a methodology question rather than a programming question, [statistics.se] would be a better fit.

Comment: What makes you think that cluster analysis usually considers only two parameters? You can try virtually any clustering and see which one gives the best results.